# Bootstrap scrollspy with angular-ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I've been banging my head trying to make scrollspy work. I'm currently doing a project scaffolded by `yeomans angular generator` with `angular-ui router`. It seems i'm in bad luck using any of the data-spy things.

**Can anyone take a look what could be the cause?**

*Code snippets:*

index.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        .. omitted
        <div id="char-nav" class="collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class=""><a href="#char-identity">Identity</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#char-attributes">Attributes</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#char-skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#char-spells">Spells</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#char-passives">Passives</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#char-equipment">Equipment</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#char-consumables">Consumables</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
...
<div class="container">

    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <my-notification></my-notification>
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div> 
...omitted
```

character.html

```
<div id="character-views" data-offset-top="0" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#char-nav">
    <div class="character-view" ng-include="'views/character/identity.html'"></div>
    <div class="character-view" ng-include="'views/character/attributes.html'"></div>
    <div class="character-view" ng-include="'views/character/skills.html'"></div>
    <div class="character-view" ng-include="'views/character/spells.html'"></div>
    <div class="character-view" ng-include="'views/character/passives.html'"></div>
    <div class="character-view" ng-include="'views/character/equipment.html'"></div>
    <div class="character-view" ng-include="'views/character/consumables.html'"></div>
</div>
```

The character page is built up by several partials, this is the page i wish to spy on.

Any of the pages in my list of ng-includes start with a header like so:

```
<header id="char-identity" class="character-view-header">Identity</header>
<hr>
```

Comment: In what order are you loading your JS libraries?  I.e., is it possible that scrollspy is building its functionality prior to your angular partials loading?  Also, are you applying relative positioning, as the bootstrap docs say you must? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: It loads as follows: jquery.js -> angular.js -> bootstrap.js -> more..
edit: i've supplied the div #character-views with position: relative; yes.

Answer (score 0):

This [AngularStrap project](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) can help you.